# AppEngine java.util.Date with Timezone in Struts2

Tags: java, google-app-engine, datetime, struts2

Im using Struts2 in Google App Engine.

I have `java.util.Date` property in an entity.

```
private Date date = null;

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}
public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

I want to display the date with our `timezone` which is `GMT+8`. So I have the following in my view:

```
<s:date name="dateAdded" format="MMM. d, yyyy / hh:mm a" timezone="GMT+08:00" />
```

But it is not displaying the correct time for `GMT+8`.

Anybody can explain the behaviour? How to display it in `GMT+8`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the timezone name:

```
      <s:date name="dateAdded" format="MMM. d, yyyy / hh:mm a" timezone="PST" />
```

or

```
      <s:date name="dateAdded" format="MMM. d, yyyy / hh:mm a" 
                                               timezone="America/Los_Angeles" />
```

Comment: it is not working...it always gives utc time converted from data on server time